# Не работает audio элемент после клонирования

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если взять блоки, внутри которых есть элемент audio и через jquery сделать clone() этих самых блоков, то после вставки в другое место тег audio работать не будет. Это как то лечится или нет ? Или дело в плагине для audio (plyr) ? Пример ниже

Пример

```
<div class="block">
   <audio class="player" controls >
      <source src="lol.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
   </audio>
</div>
```

Делаю

```
var clon = $('.block').clone() 
// Или так
var clon = $('.block').html()
```

Затем в нужное место вставляю так

```
$('место').html(clon);
```

Comment: Во-первых, в показанном вами коде не видно никакого plyr. Во-вторых, что значит «работать не будет»?

Comment: А что показывать ? Способ инициализации ? Да пожалуйста Plyr.setup('.player', { controls }); где controls - элементы панели управления. Во втором случае то и значит - не будет работать ни 1 из элементов аудио, включая воспроизведение. Полагаю дело в плагине все же т.к. при ре-инициализации создается дубликат аудио и все работает

Comment: Если плагин имеет какое-то внутреннее состояние вешает какие-то обработчики на html-элементах, то при дублировании html-кода всё это конечно же не дублируется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Plyr при инициализации хранит ссылку на элемент. А когда Вы клонировали элемент, то Plyr об этом ничего не знает

Comment: В нем есть нечто подобное методу refresh..update ? Я только destroy нашел, но мне кажется глупо делать destroy и затем заново инициализировать плагин